# Zend Loader Plugin Loader Exception

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework

Whilst using to use the Zend Framework Validation features, I came across the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' 
    with message 'Plugin by name '0' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_Validate_: Zend/Validate/' 
    in /var/www/platform/lib/Zend/Loader/PluginLoader.php:406 
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/platform/lib/Zend/Filter/Input.php(1108): Zend_Loader_PluginLoader->load('0') 
#1 /var/www/platform/lib/Zend/Filter/Input.php(1089): Zend_Filter_Input->_getFilterOrValidator('validate', Array) 
#2 /var/www/platform/lib/Zend/Filter/Input.php(867): Zend_Filter_Input->_getValidator(Array) 
#3 /var/www/platform/lib/Zend/Filter/Input.php(786): Zend_Filter_Input->_validate() 
#4 /var/www/platform/lib/Zend/Filter/Input.php(414): Zend_Filter_Input->_process() 
#5 /var/www/platform/app/controllers/admin/MatchfindersubjectsController.php(90): Zend_Filter_Input->hasMissing() 
#6 /var/www/platform/lib/Zend/Controller/Action.php(513): Admin_MatchFinderSubjectsController->addAction() 
#7 /var/www/platform/lib/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(289): Zend_C in /var/www/platform/lib/Zend/Loader/PluginLoader.php on line 406
```

Whilst using this code:

```
/**
 * Handle the index
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function addAction()
{
    $filters = [
        'subject'      => 'StringTrim',
        'gender'       => 'Digits'
    ];

    $validators = [
        'subject' => [
            'presence' => 'required'
        ],
        'gender'  => [
            new Zend_Validate_Int(),
            [ 'Between' => 0, 2 ],
            'Digits'
        ]
    ];


    $data = new Zend_Filter_Input( $filters, $validators );
    $data->setData( $_POST );

    $x = $data->hasMissing();

    die( var_export( $data ) );
}
```

I can't seem to find out:

1. Why it's trying to load '0'
2. How to make it work properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your Between validator.

Try to change

```
[ 'Between' => 0, 2 ],
```

by

```
new Zend_Validate_Between(['min' => 0, 'max' => 2]),
```

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it.